# Need help regarding DocuSign eSignature url?

Tags: docusignapi

We are using DocuSign Apex Toolkit to generate & wned a DocuSign envelope whenever a new record is created and storing the envelope ID on the parent record. We have a lightning component on which we want to display the Envelope as an Iframe. We are using DocuSign "getSigningUrl" & "getEmbeddedSigningUrl" methods. The former one returns "null" & later one is giving error as "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope.". Please suggest.

using embedded method

```
Url retUrl = new Url('[sfdc base url]');
String envelopeID = 'B33EBEFD-A64F-4D86-9034-6700AFB22EEE';
dfsle.UUID uid = dfsle.UUID.parse(envelopeID);
Url u = dfsle.SigningService.getEmbeddedSigningUrl(uid,retUrl);
System.debug('u---->'+u);
```

usign signing url method

```
String envelopeID = 'a271h000000L55d';
dfsle.Envelope e = dfsle.EnvelopeService.getEnvelope(envelopeID);
System.debug('e---->'+e);
Url retUrl = new Url('[sfdc base url]');
Url u = dfsle.SigningService.getSigningUrl(e,retUrl,true );
System.debug('u---->'+u);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure:

1. The envelope is sent. It is not in "draft" state and is not in any other state (like Completed or Void)
2. The userID for the signer is the correct email/name combination for the recipient for this envelope.
3. Your envelopeID is valid. In your second code your envelope is not a GUID. EnvelopeID is always a GUID.